# Why don’t video game consoles have seizure warnings anymore?

Tags: disclaimers

On the Wii, every time you’d start it up there would be a big screen with white text on black saying that it can cause seizures in a small group of people. I’ve heard that the PlayStation 3 also has this.

However, the 3DS, Wii U, PlayStation 4, and Nintendo Switch never require you to see this—it is in a manual or hidden somewhere in some software built-in but not ever opened by normal users.

Why did this change? **Was there some legal decision or law that changed that caused this disclaimer to not be legally necessary?**

Answer (score 6):

### No law change AFAIK - a technology change

LED TVs don’t flicker at frequencies that can cause seizures like cathode ray tubes could.